# How to parse an article from web-page using Regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex, mechanize

I have an article on page and I need to parse all text.

I know that an article is more than 15 words, joined with symbols ' ' or ',' or '-', or ':', or '.'.

How can I write a Regexp with Ruby to analyze article on a page and parse it?

For example this: http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/20/sports/baseball/for-the-mets-an-afterglow-then-realitys-harsh-light.html?ref=sports&_r=0

I need to parse the main text: `ATLANTA — From the sublime emotional high provided by Matt Harvey and Zack Wheeler, the Mets’ young, hard-throwing right-handers, the team on Wednesday descended back to the realities of its everyday existence...`

I know how to parse and get content of a page, but I don't know how to write it on a Regexp!
To analyze parent HTML tag with needed text, I must write some Regexp to check rule: 
article is more than 15 words, joined only with symbols ' ' or ',' or '-', or ':', or '.'.

Comment: need more information,sample strings or inputs and expected output too.

Comment: Mechanize comes with nokogiri in it. So, you can use all the nokogiri methods from the mechanize instance. There are lots of tutorials and docs around to demonstrate this.

Comment: Use **Nokogiri** whenever any scrapping needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri.html) to meet your needs. This is an awesome gem for web scraping.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/20/sports/baseball/for-the-mets-an-afterglow-then-realitys-harsh-light.html?ref=sports&_r=1&'))
str = doc.at_css('div.articleBody > nyt_text > p').text 

puts str
# >> ATLANTA — From the sublime emotional high provided by Matt Harvey and Zack Wheeler, the Mets’ young, hard-throwing right-handers, the team on Wednesday descended back to the realities of its everyday existence.  

str.scan(/\w+/)
# => ["ATLANTA",
#     "From",
#     "the",
#     "sublime",
#     "emotional",
#     "high",
#     "provided",
#     "by",
#     "Matt",
#     "Harvey",
#     "and",
#     "Zack",
#     "Wheeler",
#     "the",
#     "Mets",
#     "young",
#     "hard",
#     "throwing",
#     "right",
#     "handers",
#     "the",
#     "team",
#     "on",
#     "Wednesday",
#     "descended",
#     "back",
#     "to",
#     "the",
#     "realities",
#     "of",
#     "its",
#     "everyday",
#     "existence"]
```

***I know that article is more than 15 words:***

```
str.scan(/\w+/).size > 15 # => true
```

***joined with symbols ' ' or ',' or '-', or ':', or '.':***

```
[' ',',','-',':','.'].map{|i| str.include? i}
# => [true, true, true, false, false]
```